# Keeping the same distance no matter the string length

Tags: python-3.x

How can I print this list:

```
password               [Status: 301, Size: 228, Words: 9, Lines: 7]
friends             [Status: 301, Size: 227, Words: 9, Lines: 7]
madison          [Status: 301, Size: 227, Words: 9, Lines: 7]
austin            [Status: 301, Size: 226, Words: 9, Lines: 7]
```

To became this way:

```
password                [Status: 301, Size: 228, Words: 9, Lines: 7]
friends                 [Status: 301, Size: 227, Words: 9, Lines: 7]
madison                 [Status: 301, Size: 227, Words: 9, Lines: 7]
austin                  [Status: 301, Size: 226, Words: 9, Lines: 7]
```

The variables are the numbers!
I expect this output in the console!

Comment: do you expect this output in the console? or in a file? please clarify. also, please add what have you tried so far?

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar I expect the output in the console